# Отправка ajax после отправки других ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток! есть следующая задача, нужно отправить 2 параллельных ajax запроса, когда оба придут успешно, нужно отправить третий ajax

Comment: и в чем вопрос то? где ваш код?

Comment: вопрос в том как сделать то что я описал выше, как я напишу код если в этом и есть суть вопроса?

Comment: По поводу `как я напишу код`. Возможно вы умеете отправлять один ajax, или 2 параллельно, и сложность только дождаться ответа от обоих. Откуда мы можем знать? Вы же не написали исходных данных, только желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

**Пример:**

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
   // Здесь будет выполняться код, после выполнения всех 4 AJAX-запросов
});

function ajax1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  yourJsonData,            
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: вы видели `jquery` в тэгах вопроса?

Comment: @teran я и не видел что кто то запрещает использовать **jquery** для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get?req=1').then(res => res.json()),
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get?req=2').then(res => res.json())
])
.then(results => {
  let a, b;
  [a, b] = results;
  console.log(a.args, b.args);
  return fetch('https://httpbin.org/get?req=3').then(res => res.json())
}).then(third => console.log(third.args));
```